# Leafletjs, pre-defined markers, Checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I seen an answer done by Alexandru Pufan, his example to answer another question from another user is exactly what I am looking for but with out the map.on('click').

What I am trying to achieve is having predefined markers with locations communicate with my check box.

```
<div id="topcontrol" style="height: 35px; background-color: #000000; bottom: 0px; position: inherit; width: 100%; padding-left: 10px;">
    <div id="layercontrol">
        <span class="layerbox">
            <input type="image" src="assets/citycon1.png" title="City" checked id="citybox" type="checkbox" value="         cityMarkers">
            <label class="labelbox" for="citybox"></label>
        </span>
```

Above is the check box that I have made.
Below is the marker that I have created for a certain location. By default it should be hidden until called about the checkbox and removed once the user clicks again.

```
var cityMarkers = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'assets/cityMarker.png',
    iconSize: [75, 50],
    iconAnchor: [38, 45],
});

L.marker([-17.726706, -42.099609],{
    icon: cityMarkers,
    draggable: false,
}).addTo(map);
```

here is the example that Alexandru Pufan made:
[For example](http://jsfiddle.net/956s4Ld2/2/)

Comment: I have finally cracked the egg on this one and figured it out. Thank you for anyone that viewed the question.